# Using MVC with a retained mode renderer

Tags: architecture, mvc

I am using a retained mode renderer similar to the display lists in Flash. In other words, I have a scene graph data structure called the `Stage` to which I add the graphical primitives I would like to see rendered, such as images, animations, text. For simplicity I'll refer to them as `Sprites`.

Now I'm implementing an architecture which is becoming very similar to MVC, but I feel that that instead of having to create `View` classes, that the sprites already behave pretty much like `Views` (except for not being explicitly connected to the `Model`). And since the `Model` is only changed through the `Controller`, I could simply update the view together with the `Model` in the controller, as in the example below:

**Example 1**

```
class Controller
{
    Model model;
    Sprite view;
    void TeleportTo(Vector2 position) { model.Position = view.Position = position; }
}
```

The alternative, I think, would be to create `View` classes that wrap the sprites, make the model observable, and make the view react to changes on the model. This seems like a lot of extra work and boilerplate code, and I'm not seeing the benefits if I'm just going to have one view per controller.

**Example 2**

```
class Controller
{
    Model model;
    View view;
    void TeleportTo(Vector2 position) { model.Position = position; }
}

class View
{
    Model model;
    Sprite sprite;
    View() { model.PropertyChanged += UpdateView; }
    void UpdateView() { sprite.Position = model.Position; }
}
```

So, how is MVC or more specifically, the View, usually implemented when using a retained-mode renderer? And is there any reason why I shouldn't stick with example 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210026/is-the-mvc-design-pattern-used-in-commercial-computer-games

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I've recently written as answer to another question, I tried to adapt the MVC pattern to game entities. My advice is: forget it.

Have a look to a Entity based system to achieve data/graphic/logic uncoupling: [Implementing features in an Entity System](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32693/implementing-features-in-an-entity-system)

however, if you really want to stick with the MVC pattern what I used to do is to inject the model both into the controller and the view. The view was then using the model to update itself (more or less like your second case)

Comment: +1 for Entity/Component. Its saving my a lot of code compared to my previous deep-hierarchy approach.